# Mi botón de hangouts no funciona desde el movil

Tags: botón, programación-móvil

este es el código que tengo en mi web:

```
<script src="https://apis.google.com/js/platform.js" async defer></script>
<div 
   class="g-hangout" 
   data-render="createhangout" 
   data-initial_apps="[{ app_id : 'xxxx-123456'}]" 
   data-invites="[{ id : 'xxxxx@gmail.com', invite_type : 'EMAIL' }]">
 </div>
```

Funciona bien desde el ordenador, pero desde el movil me redirige a Google Play para descargarme la app. Y como ya la tengo, le doy a abrir. Cuando le doy a abrir, el link ya se ha perdido...

como puedo solucionar esto? Gracias!!! :D